# Getting error after adding Hystrix command

Tags: java, spring-boot, hystrix

After adding the Hystrix command am getting the following error -

```
Error executing HystrixCommand.run(). Proceeding to fallback logic ...: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No thread-bound request found: Are you referring to request attributes outside of an actual web request, or processing a request outside of the originally receiving thread? If you are actually operating within a web request and still receive this message, your code is probably running outside of DispatcherServlet: In this case, use RequestContextListener or RequestContextFilter to expose the current request. at org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes(RequestContextHolder.java:131) at
```

My application class looks like this -

```
@SpringBootApplication 
@EnableDistributedSession(regionName="DATASERVICES")
@EnableDiscoveryClient
@EnableCircuitBreaker
public class SampleApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SampleApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

I have seen the error is happening at the line where we are trying to get the session in Service class. My service class where I have implemented the Hystrix looks like this -

```
@Service
public class TransactionsUSStandardServiceImpl implements TransactionsUSStandardService {

   @Autowired
   private RestTemplate restTemplate;

   @Autowired
   HttpServletRequest request;

   @Override
   @HystrixCommand(commandKey = "getXyzCommand", threadPoolKey = "getXyzThreadPoolKey", fallbackMethod = "xyzFallback")
   public List<String> getXyz(String arg1,  HttpHeaders headers, String arg2) throws Exception {
        HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
        ...
        ...
   }

   public List<String> xyzFallback(String arg1, HttpHeaders headers, String arg2, Throwable t) throws Exception {
        LOGGER.error(".......");
        throw new XyzException("Hystrix CircuitBreaker Fallback while executing getXyz() method", t);
   }

   }
```

In the SVN we kept our configuration as -

```
hystrix:
  command:
    defaultHystrixCommand:
      execution:
        isolation:
          thread:
            timeoutInMilliseconds: 30000
    getXyzCommand:
      execution:
        isolation:
          thread:
            timeoutInMilliseconds: 30000
  threadpool:
    getXyzThreadPoolKey:
      coreSize: 20
      maximumSize: 20
      maxQueueSize: 5
```

Am I missing anything in my Hystrix configuration?